# (Rails 3) Combine two queries into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these models simplified:

```
class Game::Champ < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contract, :class_name => "Game::ChampTeamContract", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :team, :through => :contract
  # Attributes: :avg => integer
end
#
class Game::Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contracts, :class_name => "Game::ChampTeamContract", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :champs, :through => :contracts
end
#
class Game::ChampTeamContract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :champ
  belongs_to :team
  # Attributes: :expired => bool, :under_negotiation => bool
end
#
```

So what I want to do here is to find all Game::Champs that **have no** Game::ChampTeamContract whatsoever OR has, but (is **not** :under_negociation OR is :expired ), sorted by Champ.avg ASC

I am kinda stuck at using two queries, concating the result and sorting it. I wish there were a better way to to it more "Railish"

**UPDATE:** Just added a constraint about :expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
Game::Champs.
  joins("left outer join game_champ_team_contracts on game_champ_team_contracts.champ_id = game_champs.id").
  where("game_champ_team_contracts.id is null or (game_champ_team_contracts.state != ? or game_champ_team_contracts.state = ?)", :under_negotiation, :expired).
  order("game_champs.avg ASC")
```

This is a fairly nasty line if left as-is, so if you use this, it needs tidying up. Use scopes or methods to split it up as much as possible!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with a super simple query:

```
@bars1 = Bar.where(:something => 1)
@bars2 = Bar.where(:something => 2)

@bars = @bars1 + @bars2
```

Not sure if it's right, but it works...

Comment: Sorry, I read your question as you being resigned to hand writing two queries and concatenating the results.

Comment: Is this Rails3? If so, perhaps the new ActiveRelation chaining would work? Although it seems as though it may not support "Or" chaining... yet.